# Flutter APP crash after adding onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler Firebase messaging

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implement my app with onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler the app crash.
The log show `PluginRegistrantCallback is not set`

so I added:
`Application.kt`

```
package .............

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

in the same directory where `MainActivity.kt` is located.

`MainActivity.kt`

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }
}
```

still app crash the documentation is confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please verify you have set `android:name=".Application"` in `<application` tag in your android > app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: need to add this and remove ``` android:name=".MainActtivity" ``` ?

Comment: @EmanuelDeveloper You need to replace android:name=".MainActtivity" with android:name=".Application"